# How to display a javascript object as hex data in console.log

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am an embedded C developer, but there is some TypeScript (javascript?) code that performs various hash and sign operations.  I am trying to compare what it is generating to what happens in C on another platform to make them compatible. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out any way to dump the object to the terminal as simple hex data using something like console.log().  As you may have figured out, I am not a javascript developer.

Comment: what is `the object` you need in hex?

Comment: You can might be able to do so using `JSON.stringify(obj)` to convert your object to a JSON string and `charCodeAt` to get each char unicode value: `console.log([...JSON.stringify(obj)].map((ch)=> ch.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).join(''));